# Facebook comment url is unreachable

Tags: facebook, comment-form

i've added facebook comments on my wordpress blog, it's working fine and everything but on some pages it displays the comment box and under it it gives a warning url is unreachable and it doesn't show the moderator's setting either when it shows that warning.

am using cloudflare along with w3c cache is that will help.

i tried clearing cache and setting cloudflare as a development mode but it still the same.

Answer (score 1):

i've figured out the problem of the issue in my blog, it might help others too. I had lazy load installed and when Facebook tried to read the website, it reads it partially so it cause ssome sort of an error:

> **Partial Content**
>
> The server is delivering only part of the resource due to a range header sent by the client. The range header is used by tools like wget to enable resuming of interrupted downloads, or split a download into multiple simultaneous streams.

Hope it helps!